# Hot reloading android emulator CTRL + m doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having problem to hot reload my application in emulator. I was guided to use CTRL + m shortcut or R + R, but neither of these two works as expected. Can somebody help me where could be potentially issue?
Can somebody help me?

Comment: Oh yes, the famous R + R shortcut: hold down the `R` key and simultaneously press `R`...

Comment: R+R is even not listed in android shortcuts it says clearly CTRL+M,
to open menu, but not working

Answer (score -1):

FOR WINDOWS 10 YOU NEED TO ADD THIS SO THAT YOU CAN USE CRTL+M to open debug and reload

Add environment variables

Open a File Explorer, copy and paste the following into the address bar.

Control Panel\System and Security\System

Click on Advanced system settings on the left menu.

Click on Environmental Variables at the bottom.

Click on New to add a user variable (the top section).

You’ll be adding two:

Variable Value ANDROID_HOME C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre

Then under System variables (the bottom section), click on the Path variable and click on Edit.

On the pop-up window, click on New to add another variable:

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Click OK, OK